# Find two numbers in a sorted array whose sum is closest to a given number

Tags: algorithm, haskell

> Given a sorted array and a number x, find a pair in array whose sum is closest to x.

Here's my solution:

```
import Data.List (minimumBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

closestPairSum :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> a -> (a, a)
closestPairSum xs n = snd $ minimumBy (comparing fst) pairs
  where 
    pairs = sums xs (reverse xs)
    sums xxs@(x:xs) yys@(y:ys) = let sum = x + y in
      if n < sum
      then (sum - n, (x, y)) : sums xxs ys
      else (n - sum, (x, y)) : sums xs yys
    sums _ _ = []
```

I'm mostly self-taught, so I would love to know in which ways my code is not according to common practice. More specifically:

- How can I more clearly align my `let`-`in` and `if`-`then`-`else` expressions?
- I use an intermediate list of `(a, (a, a))` tuples, which I'm not thrilled about. Is there a more elegant way to do this, without sacrificing performance?
- I'm on the fence about `sum xs (reverse xs)` vs `sum xs $ reverse xs`. Is this just considered nitpicking, or do people have a strong opinion about this?
- Would it make more sense to swap the parameters of this function? I have the feeling that `a` would usually precede `[a]` with pointfree style in mind, but I'm not sure about this one.
- Anything else that I might not have thought of :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - How can I more clearly align my `let`-`in` and `if`-`then`-`else` expressions?

Well, that's up to you, to be honest. You could put `let ... in` into a new line, for example:

```
sums xxs@(x:xs) yys@(y:ys) = 
  let sum = x + y 
  in if n < sum
     then (sum - n, (x, y)) : sums xxs ys
     else (n - sum, (x, y)) : sums xs yys
sums _ _ = []
```

I usually prefer guards:

```
sums xxs@(x:xs) yys@(y:ys) = 
  | n < sum   = (sum - n, (x, y)) : sums xxs ys
  | otherwise = (n - sum, (x, y)) : sums xs yys
  where sum = x + y 
sums _ _ = []
```

I said "usually", because I don't like the dangling `sums` at the end.

> - I use an intermediate list of `(a, (a, a))` tuples, which I'm not thrilled about. Is there a more elegant way to do this, without sacrificing performance?

It's fine. `sortOn` from `Data.List` basically uses the same approach:

```
sortOn f = map snd . sortBy (comparing fst) . map (\x -> let y = f x in y `seq` (y, x))
```

If something is fine enough for the standard library, it should be fine enough for you. Note that the `seq` might be necessary to yield more performance.

> - I'm on the fence about `sum xs (reverse xs)` vs `sum xs $ reverse xs`. Is this just considered nitpicking, or do people have a strong opinion about this?

That's nitpicking. Some people prefer `($)`, since you cannot accidentally forget a `)`, others prefer parentheses, since they are easier to understand for beginners. The generated program will behave the same.

> - Would it make more sense to swap the parameters of this function? I have the feeling that `a` would usually precede `[a]` with pointfree style in mind, but I'm not sure about this one.

If this function will be part of a collection, then it's more important that all your functions follow the same style. Other than that, it's preferred that you use the argument which will change seldom first, or, if it's using a container, the container last. So yes, your function would be a perfect candidate for switching.

> - Anything else that I might not have thought of :)

Yes. Don't use reserved names, if possible. `sum` is defined in the `Prelude`, you've used it to bind `x + y`. Also don't use the same names twice. You've used `xs` both in your `closestPairSum` as well as in `sums`. This can lead to errors when you refactor your function.

Other than that: Well done. For comparison, here is how I would write your function:

```
import Data.List (minimumBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

closestPairSum :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> [a] -> (a, a)
closestPairSum n = snd . minimumBy (comparing fst) . pairs
  where 
    pairs xs = sums xs (reverse xs)

    sums [] _ = []
    sums _ [] = []
    sums xxs@(x:xs) yys@(y:ys)
      | n < s     = (s - n, (x, y)) : sums xxs ys -- sum greater than n, use lesser y
      | otherwise = (n - s, (x, y)) : sums xs yys -- sum lesser than n, use greater x
      where
        s = x + y
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate review! I don't really understand why `seq` is used there, though. I know what it does, but I don't see the point of using it there. Can you explain?

Comment: @TimVermeulen [it was part of the patch](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9004), although it was missing in the [proposal](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2014-April/022489.html). The rational is missing, but since we need to evaluate `f x` either way, there is no harm in adding `seq` at this point. On the contrary: we have to save one thunk less (per element). It's often a good idea to have something in WHNF (or even NF) if you know that you're going to use it.

Comment: Alright, that's something to think about. :)

Answer (score 2):

The "intermediate array" takes no extra space due to lazy evaluation. `minimumBy . comparing` is `minimumOn`. Yes, swapping the parameters makes sense. Inline `then` and `else` once more. I wouldn't worry so much about constant factors - have you compiled it with -O2 and tested (eg with criterion)?

import Data.List (minimumOn)

```
closestPairSum :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> [a] -> (a, a)
closestPairSum n xs = minimumOn (abs . (n-) . uncurry (+)) pairs where
  pairs = sums xs (reverse xs)
  sums xxs@(x:xs) yys@(y:ys) = (x, y) : if n < x + y
    then sums xxs ys
    else sums xs yys
  sums _ _ = []
```

Comment: Your solution computes `x + y` twice for each `(x, y)` pair, right? Also, I can't seem to import `minimumOn` - do I need to install it somehow?

Comment: @TimVermeulen: It doesn't exist. It [was proposed](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2659), but [not included](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/a2f39da0461b5da62a9020b0d98a1ce2765dd700/libraries/base/changelog.md). Maybe Gurkenglas uses a custom Prelude that contains `minimumOn`. But it's not [in the GHC source](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=minimumOn). Also, yes. `x + y` gets computed twice.